# jQuery - Return all objects in an array that contain a text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is it possible to search an array for a string of text, then return the contents of the objects which contain it?

For example:

```
<script>
    var itemsArray = ["2Bedroom Ensuite 2Bathroom", "1Bedroom Ensuite 1Bathroom", "3Bedroom 2Bathroom"];
    var searchTerm = 'ensuite';
    var results = $.searchThing('itemsArray', searchTerm);
    document.write(results);
</script>
```

The above hypothetical script (where 'searchThing' is the method - if it exists) should write

```
2Bedroom Ensuite 2Bathroom
2Bedroom Ensuite 2Bathroom
```

Does this exist? How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask you why you're trying to do in jQuery something that could be easily made with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ES5 `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
var results = itemsArray.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
});
```

Note that older browsers don't support the `.filter()` method. For supporting those browsers [you can use a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

edit: You can also use the jQuery `$.grep()` utility function:

```
var results = $.grep(itemsArray, function(elem) {
    return elem.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Absolutely correct and the way to go. Use jQuery for manipulating the DOM, but javascript for manipulating variables.

Comment: well, there's `$.grep` - basically, an alias to `filter`, but works in iE8

Comment: @thg435 Yes, thanks for mentioning that. I had forgotten the `$.grep()` method.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var searchTerm = 'ensuite';
var itemsArray = ["2Bedroom Ensuite 2Bathroom", "1Bedroom Ensuite 1Bathroom", "3Bedroom 2Bathroom"];
for(var i=0;i<itemsArray.length;i++){
 var str=itemsArray[i];
  if(str.indexOf(searchTerm ) >= 0){
   //it contains searchterm do something with it.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do in jQuery (sort of), but it isn't necessary to use jQuery. Here's a jQuery solution anyway

```
var itemsArray = ['asdf','1234'];
var searchTerm = 'asdf';
var results=[];
$.each(itemsArray, function(i,e){
    if(e.indexOf('asdf') > -1)
        results.push(e);
});
```

I would prefer undefined's solution personally.

Comment: `.indexOf` is not applicable if you want to search for an exact word. For example if `searchTerm = 'as' ` the above code will still work.
What should be used if we want an exact match.